# Purpose of Datestamp Column in Database Table

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I'm working on building a webapp and received a partial database schema. Some of the tables have datestamp columns to keep track of when the record was last updated.

My question is twofold: what is/are the purpose(s) or benefit(s) of tracking when a record was updated, and when should it be done?

Thanks

Comment: Humans by nature like controlling stuffs, therefore if you are able to know when something was update you'll feel a bit more in control, it serves the same purpose of having logs.

Comment: Depends on why you have the timestamp(s).  Usually, there's one for the insert and one for the update.  While this doesn't substitute for a change log if one is required, it does give an easy indicator of the age of the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want an "updated_at" column if a user wants to sort or filter by when a row was last updated.

Look at Google Drive's main listing window. There is a column "Last Modified" that you can sort on, to look at documents that you most recently modified. You would need a database column with the last modified date to be able to sort by that value.

Another example is an API where API users only want to download new information, so they could filter (using a WHERE clause) for records that had changed only since their last download.